# Short story where people travel in solo space ships, one stops to protect a developing planet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Many years ago I read a short story in a magazine. I think it was in *Analog* or *Asimov's*.

It was set in the far future and humanity had evolved to become essentially immortal. Many humans travelled around on ships, one person to a ship. The ships travelled the universe on some sort of energy beam.

The story basically revolved around a conversation between two humans. One was going to stop travelling so he could watch over a planet and protect the intelligence developing on that planet from things like natural disasters.

That's all I really remember about it. I'm guessing it was published sometime in the early 90s.